# If I evaluate a limit as n goes to infinity and I have a O(1/n^3) term being multiplied by n^3, then does this term still go to zero in the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

The term would then be in O(1), I believe.  Do I still interpret this term as having a limit of zero, as n goes to infinity?

Thanks,

Comment: Well is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^3} \cdot n^3 =0$?

Comment: Hi @DominicMichaelis, what if I intentionally put some terms into O(1/n^3) but the terms actually go to zero faster?  E.g., put 1/n^4 , 1/n^5 into O(1/n^3).  Then n^3 * O(1/n^3), although this is now O(1), my terms are still going to zero ... but the upper bound is just different now.  Do you think this works?  I see a couple solutions are using this weird strategy, and I am essentially trying to mimic this technique but want to make sure I am actually interpreting the solution correctly.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. By definition $O(1)$ is a map $f$ such that there is some $M \geq 0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all suitable $x$.

Comment: I think I see what's going on now @Gudson Chou.  If I put a 1/n^3 term and a 1/n^4 term ... both in O(1/n^2), then my terms go to zero *faster* than O(1/n^2).  Then differentiating the big-O term gives O(1/n^3), but my terms go to zero at least at the speed of 1/n^3.  Finally, multiplying by n^3, although putting my terms now in O(1), they are still terms going to zero.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: I sort of need this construction to make my answer work, i.e., to get the correct limit that matches the solution, so I want to argue that this O(1) term is indeed zero, the limit.

Comment: Yes; the bottom line is that an $O(1)$ map is not necessarily $o(1)$, but the converse is true. :)

Comment: Ok got it - thanks so much @gudsonchou.  Have a great night :-)